# Relative differences between two plots with different sizes in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

In `MATLAB`, I am trying to get the relative difference between two curves but I couldn't. I am interested in the differences in the y-axis in the common range of x-axis. The problem that I am facing is that one of the curves has 29 points and the other has 60 points as shown in the attached plot. Is there way to get the difference between these two plots ?[image]

Comment: Have a look [here](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html?s_tid=srchtitle). Interpolate both curves for common x values and then subtract as shown for example on [matlabcentral](http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/65868-finding-difference-between-two-curves)

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly your question, I believe the easiest way would be to take the values of your larger vectors that are the closest in terms of X to the values of your smaller vector.

By that, I mean that if your smaller vector has some value y at every integer x (e.g. X = [1:29] & Y = rand(29,1)), you should look for the y values in your larger vector that are associated with the X closest to the integers [1:29] and recreate a same size vector. Hence, you compare only 29 values for each vector that are the closest as possible in terms of X).

Another suggestion, if the curves are smooth, would be to create news points in the smaller curve vector. The new points could be the mean of 2 other points (in terms of Y and X). Hence, if you have a curve with 2 points, (1,2) & (3,4), you could create the point (2,3) that would smooth the function. You can do that until your 2 vectors have the same number of points. This might induce some error if the X values of each point are quite different for each vector.

Anyway, these are suggestions and there are probably ways to be even more precise!